# Exception Thrown: 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' in EPPlus.dll

Tags: indexoutofrangeexception

Using Visual Studio Community 2017 And AdvancedHMI to create a PC based HMI application. I have several running with no issue so moving onto something new.
On each line I have 7 array's (500 real numbers each array) and would like to capture this data daily and save to Excel.
Using EPPlus and AdvancedHMI I have the following code.

```
Private Sub DataSubscriber1_DataChanged(sender As Object, e As Drivers.Common.PlcComEventArgs) Handles DataSubscriber1.DataChanged
    If e.ErrorId = 0 AndAlso e.Values.Count > 0 AndAlso e.Values(0) = "True" Then
        Console.WriteLine("About to read the data")
        Dim MyValues() As String = EthernetIPforCLXCom1.Read("VCell_1A_FES_Cycle_Average[0]", 500)
        Console.WriteLine(MyValues.Length & "elements read.")

        '* Transfer the values to Excel
        Using ExcelPackage As New OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(New System.IO.FileInfo("c:\Data.xlsx"))
            For I = 0 To MyValues.Length - 1
                Console.WriteLine("Element " & I & "=" & MyValues(I))
                ExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, I + 1).Value = MyValues(I)

            Next
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

Running this and triggering my tag vale to execute the datascriber I get the following.

> About to read the data
>
> 500Elements read.
>
> Element 0=87.945
>
> Exception Thrown: 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' in EPPlus.dll

Everything looks like it should work but I am very new to VB or any type of coding for that matter. My forte' is PLC ladder logic.

Thanks.

Comment: Try writing a test value (not from the array) to the Excel file before the line `* Transfer the values to Excel`. Are you still getting the out of range exception? If not, stop writing the values to the Excel file in your loop and simply write the values to console. Does that work?

Comment: Thanks, when I get into work tonight I will give it a shot.

Comment: I was able to write the 500 tag array to console without issue. I modified my  loop and all working OK now. Thanks.

Comment: You should post the modified code as an answer, in case anyone ever has the same issue. Glad you solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have working. The Datascriber has a trigger tag in the PLC. Once it's triggered it collects the array data, all 500 elements. Creates a new Excel file and writes the data to Column A, Cells 1-500

```
Private Sub DataSubscriber1_DataChanged(sender As Object, e As Drivers.Common.PlcComEventArgs) Handles DataSubscriber1.DataChanged

    If e.ErrorId = 0 AndAlso e.Values.Count > 0 AndAlso e.Values(0) = "True" Then
        Console.WriteLine("About to read the data")
        Dim MyValues() As String = EthernetIPforCLXCom1.Read("VCell_1A_FES_Cycle_Average[0]", 500)
        Console.WriteLine(MyValues.Length & "elements read.")

        Transfer the values to Excel

        Using ExcelPackage As New OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(New IO.FileInfo("C:\Data.xlsx"))
            ExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("test")
            For Index = 0 To MyValues.Length - 1
                Console.WriteLine("Element " & Index & "=" & MyValues(Index))
                Dim ws As OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet = ExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets(1)
                Console.WriteLine("Worksheet OK")
                Dim CellNum As String = "A" & (Index + 1)
                ws.Cells(CellNum).Value = MyValues(Index)
            Next
            ExcelPackage.Save()
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```